# Prism ViewModel entry point/leave point

Tags: c#, viewmodel, prism

I'm using prism with ViewModel locator and injecting views. When using INavigationAware I can use methods to init or dispose items.

What can I do to init the view and dispose/unsubscribe items if the view is fixed in a region? I want to init or cleanup if the outter ViewModel is started/left.